# Is GoldenEye: Source free?

Tags: goldeneye-source

I can't tell if you have to buy anything to play *GoldenEye: Source*. Is it free? Are there any good tutorials on getting this up and running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes here is the link to the [current download version](http://www.moddb.com/mods/goldeneye-source/downloads/goldeneye-source-beta-4-full-download-zip) if you already own HL-2

> GoldenEye: Source Beta 4 is the first major release since Beta 3.1.4 in March of 2009. Beta 4 brings us many steps closer to a final version of the mod and introduces a tremendous amount of polish in both gameplay, coding, and presentation. Some of the major changes include Rolling Explosions, Bullet Penetration, and Living Daylights, Capture the Key, and Live and Let Die gameplay scenarios. Please see the Beta 4 Change List for a complete list of changes in Beta 4.

Their [wiki](http://www.moddb.com/mods/goldeneye-source/wiki) is a good source for tutorials

If you don't have HL-2 you can get it on either [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/220/) (digital) or for [$10 online](http://www.zipzoomfly.com/jsp/ProductDetail.jsp?ProductCode=610631&prodlist=froogle) (hardcopy disk)

Comment: Although if you're getting HL2, consider getting the PC version of Orange Box.  I thought I saw a copy of it online for $20 just recently, but it's always $30 or less on Steam.

Comment: Orange box is definitely the better detail, especially because of Portal

Answer (score 2):

As with all Half-Life 2 mods, you need to own Half Life 2 *(or any other source game, eg. CS:S)* to play it.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, *GoldenEye: Source* is free and can be played without purchasing another game. Unlike what the previous answers claim, you don’t need *Half-Life 2* or any other Source game to play it. Here’s the [download page for the most recent version](https://www.moddb.com/mods/goldeneye-source). You only need Steam and Source SDK Base 2007 installed to run it, both of which are free.

> ## GoldenEye: Source Installation Guide
>
> ### 1. Install Steam
>
> If you don't already have Steam installed, download it
> [here](http://store.steampowered.com/about/). If you don't have an
> account, signing up is easy, and you don't have to make any purchases
> to play GoldenEye: Source.
>
> Also necessary is Source SDK Base 2007. Steam will install this for
> you if you don't have it, but you can also install it from the Tools
> section of your Steam library.
>
> ### 2. Install GoldenEye: Source
>
> Download links for GoldenEye: Source can be found on the
> [download](https://www.geshl2.com/go/download) page.
>
> **If you downloaded the installer**: After the download completes, simply run the installer and follow the instructions.
>
> **If you downloaded the zip file**: Please follow the steps in [this guide](https://wiki.geshl2.com/goldeneye/manual_installation).
>
> ### 3. Restart Steam
>
> For GoldenEye: Source to appear in your games library, Steam must be
> restarted after the installation is completed.
>
> **Now that you've made it this far, you are ready to play GoldenEye: Source!**
>
> If you encounter any issues, check [Client
> Troubleshooting](https://wiki.geshl2.com/goldeneye/playerguides/troubleshooting).

Source: ["Installation Guide", The GoldenEye: Source Wiki](https://wiki.geshl2.com/goldeneye/installation)

Check out the [The GoldenEye: Source Wiki](https://wiki.geshl2.com/) for more information on the game.